Executing PowerShell script with arguments from C# code
Trying to execute PowerShell script with arguments but it won't work.
I am trying to execute a PowerShell script from my program, for some reason the IPAddress won't pass to the argument properly. If I run it without it, it works fine. Any advise what am I doing wrong?
private async void RunningGst()
{
    byte[] scriptBytes = Manip2Cards.Properties.Resources.run_gst;
    string script = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(scriptBytes);

    await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "powershell.exe",
                    Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"{script}\" -IPAddress {IPAddress}",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                Process process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = psi
                };

                process.Start();

                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine(output);
            });
}

Thank you

why are you using a process instead of a powershell instance?

Using the PowerShell SDK - and therefore in-process execution, which is not only faster but also preserves type fidelity - as shown in Santiago's helpful answer, is indeed preferable.

As for what you tried:
The problem is that \"{script}\" -IPAddress {IPAddress} is ultimately seen as {script} -IPAddress {IPAddress} by PowerShell, i.e. as a single piece of source code stitched together from the individual -Command arguments, after removal of syntactic (unescaped) ".
E.g., if script contains param($IpAddress) Write-Output IPAddress: $IpAddress and IPAddress contains foo, PowerShell executes
param($IpAddress) Write-Output IPAddress: $IpAddress -IpAddress foo, which does not pass -IpAddress foo as a (named) argument to the code stored in script.
As an aside: If the value of script contains " chars., they must in effect be escaped as \" in the context of your code, which with literal code in your case would require \\\"
The solution is to enclose the script value in & { ... } to ensure that it is treated like a script to which arguments can be passed:
  // ...
  Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"& {{ {script} }} -IPAddress {IPAddress}\"",
  // ...

Note:

As of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4.x, there's an experimental feature, PSCommandWithArgs that, when enabled, supports a new -CommandWithArgs CLI parameter that would work as you intended: the first argument thereafter is then considered the body of a script to execute, with all subsequent arguments being passed to that script:

  // ...
  // Use of -CommandWithArgs
  // NOTE: Only available in 7.4.x, i.e. only with pwsh.exe, not with powershell.exe
  //       and only if you run the following first, in a separate CLI call:
  //          Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSCommandWithArgs
  Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -CommandWithArgs \"{script}\" -IPAddress {IPAddress}",
  // ...



Glad to hear it, @DeanHaklai.

You should use the PowerShell SDK instead of creating a new process. You will have a much easier time with it leaving aside it is more efficient to invoke your PowerShell script in a new runspace in the same process rather than creating a new process.
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

async void RunningGst()
{
    byte[] scriptBytes = Manip2Cards.Properties.Resources.run_gst;
    string script = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(scriptBytes);

    using PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace);

    PSDataCollection<PSObject> output = await powerShell
        .AddScript(script, useLocalScope: true)
        .AddParameter("IPAddress", IPAddress)
        .InvokeAsync();

    foreach (PSObject pso in output.ReadAll())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pso.BaseObject);
    }
}

// Only needed if below PowerShell SDK 7.2.0
internal static class Extensions
{
    internal static async Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> InvokeAsync(
        this PowerShell powerShell)
    {
        using PSDataCollection<PSObject> output = [];
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output),
            powerShell.EndInvoke);
        return output;
    }
}


Thank you I will take this in mind and give it a try
